# Is there a 64-bit version of MySQL for Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, mysql, 32-bit, mysql-workbench

On the MySQL download page, there are only downloads for "Windows (x86, 32-bit)" https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

However, MySQL Workbench seems to be 64-bit, it says "Windows (x86, 64-bit)": https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

I would like to avoid 32-bit software if there is a 64-bit version, and I don't want to deal with any issues that could occur with using 32-bit MySQL with 64-bit MySQL Workbench, so I was wondering if there is any way to obtain a 64-bit version of MySQL on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to avoid 32-bit software if there is a 64-bit version, and I don't want to deal with any issues that could occur with using 32-bit MySQL with 64-bit MySQL Workbench,
> so I was wondering if there is any way to obtain a 64-bit version of MySQL on Windo

The MySQL Workbench download does not contain `MySQL Community Server 8.0.21`.  64-bit and 32-bit versions of MySQL Community Server 8.0.21 both do exist.  The description of the download you linked to has the necessary information.  You can avoid any compatibility problems with MySQL Workbench by only using the 64-bit version of the server.

> MySQL Installer is 32-bit but will install both 32 bit and 64-bit binaries.

Source: [MySQL Community Server 8.0.21](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#info-tab)